# Error in installing sentence_transformers package of python

Tags: python, pip, sentence-transformers

I need to install the package `sentence_transformers==1.1.0`. I tried in multiple ways by running the commands
`pip install sentence-transformers` and `pip install sentence_transformers`.

The error was not in `pip`, it was showing:

```
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error while installing sentence-transformers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78001556/error-while-installing-sentence-transformers)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which system or python version you are using or the cause of this error.
But you can try installing it with a virtual environment. It is always recommended to create one while working with any project.

If using Ubuntu or debian
Install venv with

`apt install python3.11-venv`

Or if you are using windows the it is already installed.

Now create the virtual environment with

```
Python -m venv env
```

env is just the name of the environment you can change it, if you want to.

Then run this to activate the environment.

```
source env/bin/activate
```

Now you can install the package you want to install.

In this case.
`pip install sentence_transformers` or
`pip install sentence_transformers==1.1.0`

**In my system I had no problem installing it with or without virtual environment. I am using windows 11 with python 3.11.8**.

Comment: Still it is showing same error ,

  FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

Comment: @badhripersonal What version of python are you using ?